# Can 5V be applied to 3.3V "5V tolerant" ADC inputs for indefinite durations?

Tags: microcontroller, adc, protection

Can 5V be applied to 3.3V "5V tolerant" ADC inputs for indefinite durations? I'm looking at hardware failure modes, I know the ADC value will be clamped at 3.3V.

I just would like to know if I should generally be cautious with 5V tolerance stated in datasheets in case some implementations are actually non-permanent protections.

[Edited out the example of the ARM LPC1768]

Comment: We are not here to read the datasheet to you.

Comment: @OlinLathrop perhaps the OP is more worried about long term over-voltage conditions on analog inputs, which state they are 5V tolerant? Who knows? Why don't you suggest ways that you have dealt with this in the past.. You are the microcontroller guru afterall

Comment: @Kyran: Either way the datasheet is the ultimate source of what is allowed, whether indefinitely or for a short time.

Comment: Page 37 of [the datasheet](http://www.nxp.com/documents/data_sheet/LPC1768_66_65_64.pdf) says the A/D converter 0 inputs all have a maximum voltage of 6v.  I don't see any reason they couldn't tolerate 5v for any extended period of time.  Extra input circuitry should not be required.  As you point out, this will max out the reading of the ADC (since its highest value is 3.3v) and make it useless.

Comment: This is not a lazy question, I mean in general. I don't like Ricardo's edit that might have made you think it was "do the work for me" (Ricardo, I'm sure you meant well). I just would like to know if I should be cautious with 5V tolerance in case some implementations are actually non-peermanent protections.

Comment: Sorry you think my edit didn't help, but I edited the question *after* Olin labeled it lazy (5 minutes later, give or take - leave your mouse over the edit time and you'll see the actual timestamps). In any case, it's perfectly fine for you to have questions like that as sometimes it's difficult to locate and parse the actual information from datasheets. As a hobbyist and newbie, I get that a lot.

Comment: But knowing how this site works, it would have helped if you had a more specific design problem to solve instead of asking a general question like you did. To me, that was the reason your question wasn't that well received by some.

Comment: Datasheet is required reading.  The research in @TCrosley 's comment should have been done by the O.P. and posted in the original question.  Occasionally one might post a question: "*I've looked in the datasheet, but couldn't find*" or "*I found something in the datasheet on p.XX, but I don't understand C and D*".  No excuse for not reading the datasheet.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, the ADC will read "max value" while the input is above the ADC reference voltage, and the internal ADC clamping diodes will be dealing with the over-voltage condition. The best thing you can do to ruggedize your ADC inputs is to use external schottky diode clamps to the 3.3V rail, and a series input resistor.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fJ1681.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Where R1 value is calculated to protect D1 and D2 from voltage clamp currents (based on the power rating of the package you choose) and R2 is optional, and is there for the same purpose - to protect the internal ADC input clamps from over-voltage currents.

Ensure that the total input impedance from the input signal and through R1 + R2 remains within spec for the ADC input (check datasheets for this).

Comment: Thanks. I'll have a look at the data sheet to see if those are already in there.

Comment: @user42875 you can also clamp the input to 5V (which is what the internal circuitry will be doing anyway) but their diodes may clamp before yours do, so going straight to 3.3V will avoid that